# How to use v-model inside select form?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Is there any way to get the a selected options in vuejs in select tags form.

Like I've this tag i can get the

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com" autofocus v-model="email">
```

Like this I want to get the select dropdown element inside the data() in vue3.
My select element is follows

```
<div class="form-floating">
    <select class="form-select" >
        <option selected>Select your category</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="c">b-</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and It is also inside form tag.

How can i also get data of it and stored in data in vuejs.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could do, `<select class="form-select" v-model="selectedItem">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a v-model to a local reactive variable :

```js
<template>
<div class="form-floating">
    <select class="form-select" v-model="selectedCategory">
        <option value="none">Select your category</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="c">b-</option>
    </select>
</div>
  
  selectedCategory: {{selectedCategory}}
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  data () {
    return {
    selectedCategory: "none"
  }
  }
});
</script>
```

[Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Hello, Is it mandatory to use defineComponent  instead of just exporting defaults

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
<select class="form-select" v-model="item">
<option value="I">I</option>
<option value="J">J</option>
<option value="K">K</option>
</select>
</template>
export default{
...
data(){
return{
item: 'K'
}
}
}
```

Here , you can make option with value K selected with v-modal="item"